# Shopify Liquid Differentiate Taxable Products

Tags: shopify, shopify-template, shopify-liquid

**Is there any solution, that can help me to Differentiate taxable products?**

**For Eg:** We need to extract only those products from a single collection, which has a variation with taxable without adding any patches with if a condition or contain operator.

**What I Tried:**

```
{% for products in collections.all.products | where : 'variants.taxable' , false %}
   ......
{% endfor %}
```

But didn't succeed. If anyone has any solution to feature this out. that will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: So you can't have a `{% if %}`? The right syntax would be `where: 'variants.taxable', false` but `variants.taxable` should not work because the where operator is not that smart. `taxable` is a property of the single variant not `variants`.

Comment: @FabioFilippi is there any direct solution except if condition ??

Comment: I can't think of anything, sorry.